# getting message for "Invalid values:" for yargs

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

I am using `yargs` to develop a cli tool . Here is simple `yargs` code to process the cli option

```
let argv = require('yargs')
    .usage('$0 <command> [option]')
    .command(
        'validate_zip',
        'validate the directory structure for the zip to be uploaded',
        {
            'validate_zip': {
                alias: 'vz'
            }
        }

    )
    .option('s', {
        alias: 'stage',
        describe: 'stage',
        type: 'string',
        choices: ['dev', 'qa', 'uat', 'prod'],
        count: true
    })
    .demandCommand(1, 'You need at least one command before moving on!')
    .help('h')
    .alias('h', 'help')
    .example('$0 validate_zip -s dev', 'testing yargs')
    .showHelpOnFail(false, "Specify --help || -h for available options")
    .argv;
```

Here is the cli command
`node testYargs.js vz -s dev` . I tried passing `"dev"`, but having the same issue.

and it displaying the following message

```
Invalid values:
  Argument: s, Given: 1, Choices: "dev", "qa", "uat", "prod"

Specify --help || -h for available options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count option should not be set to true. Count has a special meaning, indicating that the number of occurrences of a flag should be counted:

[details about count.](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/docs/api.md#countkey) can be found in original `yargs` api documentation.

So `-v -v -v` would set`v = 3`, this will break the Choices logic.

[credit to original answer.](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/1373)